# How can I uniquely identify a print queue on Windows even if the queue is renamed?

Tags: c#, windows, printing

How can I uniquely and reliably identify a Windows print queue on a given server, including across print queue renames?

I want to handle cases like the following:

1. Jdoe creates Printer A
2. My program gathers information on Printer A at some point
3. Jdoe renames Printer A to Printer AA
4. My program gathers information on Printer AA again at some point

How can I tell that Printer A and Printer AA are the same printer (with the name changed)?

I want to do this in C# supporting Windows XP/2003 and up.

Things I've tried:

On Windows 8/Server 2012 it appears that I can do this via WMI looking at CIM_LogicalDevice->DeviceID, which seems to remain consistent across renames, but in earlier versions of the OS this property just contains the queue name and changes when the queue is renamed.

I've also looked at the Win32_PnPEntity class (which doesn't contain printers pre Windows 8) and Win32_Printer class (which doesn't contain any sort of ID other than the name).

In the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Printers[printer name] has a QueueInstanceId field containing a GUID, but only in Windows 8/Server 2012. It is not present in earlier OSs.

The print spooler API and GDI print APIs both appear to identify queues by name, so I haven't found anything useful there.

Comment: Are you trying to receive some sort of event notification when this occurs, or just query it and get the latest queues?

Comment: Also, pardon my ignorance, but when you say "print queue names", that's the same thing as a print device name under Devices & Printers, right?

Comment: @AdamPlocher A notification is not necessary. I would like to be able to query periodically and recognize that Printer AA is in fact Printer A with the name changed, and to be able to do things like recognize that Document 1 printed to Printer A was sent to the same printer as Document 2 sent to Printer AA (after the rename). Also, to answer the question from your second comment, yes, we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. I have some code that lists the printer name and driver name.  Would matching the driver name (which shouldn't change) be enough of a determination that they are the same devices?  I can post it in an answer if you would like...

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I used on an old project for determining the printer name and the driver name (along with some other details of the printer).  I'm not sure if matching the driver name will be sufficient for you.  I know I've tested it on Win7 and I'm about 80% sure I tested it on XP (it was a while ago):

**Helper method that returns printer names / driver names on a system:**

```
public static List<PrinterDriverItem> GetCardPrinterList()
{
    List<PrinterDriverItem> returnValue = new List<PrinterDriverItem>();

    uint cbNeeded = 0;
    uint cReturned = 0;
    bool ret = Win32PrintApi.EnumPrinters(Win32PrintApi.PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, null, 2, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref cbNeeded, ref cReturned);

    IntPtr addr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)cbNeeded);
    ret = Win32PrintApi.EnumPrinters(Win32PrintApi.PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, null, 2, addr, cbNeeded, ref cbNeeded, ref cReturned);

    if (ret)
    {
        Win32PrintApi.PRINTER_INFO_2[] printerInfo = new Win32PrintApi.PRINTER_INFO_2[cReturned];
        int offset = addr.ToInt32();

        for (int i = 0; i < cReturned; i++)
        {
            printerInfo[i].pServerName = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(new IntPtr(offset)));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].pPrinterName = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(new IntPtr(offset)));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].pShareName = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(new IntPtr(offset)));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].pPortName = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(new IntPtr(offset)));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].pDriverName = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(new IntPtr(offset)));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].pComment = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(new IntPtr(offset)));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].pLocation = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(new IntPtr(offset)));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].pDevMode = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(new IntPtr(offset));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].pSepFile = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(new IntPtr(offset)));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].pPrintProcessor = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(new IntPtr(offset)));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].pDatatype = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(new IntPtr(offset)));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].pParameters = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(new IntPtr(offset)));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].pSecurityDescriptor = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(new IntPtr(offset));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].Attributes = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(new IntPtr(offset));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].Priority = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(new IntPtr(offset));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].DefaultPriority = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(new IntPtr(offset));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].StartTime = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(new IntPtr(offset));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].UntilTime = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(new IntPtr(offset));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].Status = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(new IntPtr(offset));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].cJobs = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(new IntPtr(offset));
            offset += 4;
            printerInfo[i].AveragePPM = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(new IntPtr(offset));
            offset += 4;

            returnValue.Add(new PrinterDriverItem() { PrinterName = printerInfo[i].pPrinterName, DriverName = printerInfo[i].pDriverName });
        }

    }

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(addr);

    return returnValue;
}
```

**Win32PrintApi class:**

```
public class Win32PrintApi
{
    public const int PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL = 0x00000002;

    [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool EnumPrinters(int Flags, string Name, uint Level, IntPtr pPrinterEnum, uint cbBuf, ref uint pcbNeeded, ref uint pcReturned);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct PRINTER_INFO_2
    {
        public string pServerName;
        public string pPrinterName;
        public string pShareName;
        public string pPortName;
        public string pDriverName;
        public string pComment;
        public string pLocation;
        public IntPtr pDevMode;
        public string pSepFile;
        public string pPrintProcessor;
        public string pDatatype;
        public string pParameters;
        public IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor;
        public uint Attributes;
        public uint Priority;
        public uint DefaultPriority;
        public uint StartTime;
        public uint UntilTime;
        public uint Status;
        public uint cJobs;
        public uint AveragePPM;
    }
}
```

EDIT: For what it's worth, I just stepped through this code to see if I could find anything unique'ish looking...  Most of those values were null or blank for me, but here are a few things:

```
Printer Name: XPS Card Printer - NEW 
Driver Name: XPS Card Printer
Port Name: USB DXP01 Port
Attributes: 2624
DevMode: 3562584
```

Not sure if that'll help...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can see where you're going with this, but I think there are a lot of cases it won't handle reliably. It's not uncommon to have multiple printers using the same driver in an office, and I don't think it would handle cases like 6 printers using the same driver all being renamed at once (e.g. to reflect a new naming scheme), or cases where one printer was deleted followed by a new printer being added using the same driver. You could perhaps make it more reliable by also looking at the port, but that's exactly the sort of rabbit hole I was hoping to avoid. +1 though.

Comment: Ahh yeah, that's true... Deleting and readding would show as the same driver and there could definitely be multiple devices with that same driver name... hmmm...

Comment: I wonder what those other values are in PRINTER_INFO_2.  I've only used the PrinterName and PrinterDriver.  Pinvoke.net has the structure but no real documentation on it.  It would be nice if there was some sort of GUID you could track that gets created upon adding a new printer.  http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/PRINTER_INFO_2.html

Comment: Made one small update to my post (at the bottom).  Not sure if it'll help you at all but it might be worth taking a gander...

Comment: For reference here's the documentation for PRINTER_INFO_2: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162845(v=vs.85).aspx. DevMode is a pointer to a struct with additional information on the printer defaults and Attributes is a flag enum with printer attributes. And yes, it would be absolutely wonderful if there were a GUID. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Per "Duplicate Installation Detection" on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, the Windows PnP manager uses driver and port name to determine a previous installation.  It may therefore be reasonable to assume you can keep track of printers using the same tactic.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use are the following functions from setup class.

- [SetupDiGetClassDevs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetclassdevsw)
- [SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdienumdeviceinfo)
- [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceregistrypropertya)
- [Hardware Class IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/system-defined-device-setup-classes-available-to-vendors)

Here is a crude sample Cpp code that I wrote. No matter if the printer is local/network/redirected rdp printer, the hardware Id will always be same even if the name is different.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SetupAPI.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "setupapi.lib")

void PrintPrinterIds(REFGUID ClassGuid)
{
    HDEVINFO hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&ClassGuid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT);
    if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        wprintf(L"Cannot get devices : %d\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    int idx = 0;
    DWORD errorVal = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    while (true)
    {
        SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData = {};
        WCHAR regProp[512];
        devInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(devInfoData);

        if (!SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, idx, &devInfoData))
        {
            errorVal = GetLastError();
            break;
        }

        if (!SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
            hDevInfo,
            &devInfoData,
            SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME,
            NULL,
            (PBYTE)regProp,
            sizeof(regProp),
            NULL))
        {
            errorVal = GetLastError();
            break;
        }

        wprintf(L"Friendly name = %s\n", regProp);

        if (!SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
            hDevInfo,
            &devInfoData,
            SPDRP_HARDWAREID,
            NULL,
            (PBYTE)regProp,
            sizeof(regProp),
            NULL))
        {
            errorVal = GetLastError();
            break;
        }

        // hardwareId is reg_multi_sz
        // Print all of the hardware ids for this device
        PWCHAR pId = regProp;
        do
        {
            wprintf(L"HardwareId = %s\n", pId);
            pId += wcslen(pId) + 1;
        } while (pId[0] != 0);

        // Point to next device
        idx++;
    }

    if (errorVal != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
    {
        printf("Error : %d\n", errorVal);
    }

    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
}

int main()
{
    // {4d36e979-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
    static const GUID PrinterClass =
    { 0x4d36e979, 0xe325, 0x11ce, { 0xbf, 0xc1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe1, 0x03, 0x18 } };
    PrintPrinterIds(PrinterClass);

    // L"{1ed2bbf9-11f0-4084-b21f-ad83a8e6dcdc}"
    static const GUID PrinterQueue =
    { 0x1ed2bbf9, 0x11f0, 0x4084, { 0xb2, 0x1f, 0xad, 0x83, 0xa8, 0xe6, 0xdc, 0xdc } };
    PrintPrinterIds(PrinterQueue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that’s something we weren’t aware of and it looks promising.