# How to uniquely identify a redirected by EasyPrint printer on an RDP session in Delphi (or via Windows API)?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I like to uniquely identify a redirected by EasyPrint printer on an RDP session in Delphi. Each time a user connects to the RDP session, the name of the printer change, e.g.: "HPLJP1606 (redirected **6**)". The last number (**6**) is always changing to ensure the printer name is unique across the server. In my program, I like to save some printer related parameters that are dependent to the printer model. I was expecting to find something like a GUID to identify the printer somewhere a bit like a MAC address. It should allow my program to ensure it's the same printer than previously selected.

Me and my colleagues looked into this solution:
[How can I uniquely identify a print queue on Windows even if the queue is renamed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960424/how-can-i-uniquely-identify-a-print-queue-on-windows-even-if-the-queue-is-rename)
This wouldn't work because the GUID is different for each session.

We also tried some system workaround to rename the printer but it's not easy to generalize.

Is there a way to identify the underlying EasyPrint printer without using the printer name in Delphi or via Windows API?

I use Delphi 10.2

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The number refers to the session id, so session 6 in this case

Answer (score 2):

I do not use delphi but this should help you. What you need to use are the following functions from setup class.

- [SetupDiGetClassDevs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetclassdevsw)
- [SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdienumdeviceinfo)
- [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceregistrypropertya)
- [Hardware Class IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/system-defined-device-setup-classes-available-to-vendors)

Here is a crude sample Cpp code that I wrote. No matter if the printer is local/network/redirected rdp printer, the hardware Id will always be same even if the name is different.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SetupAPI.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "setupapi.lib")

void PrintPrinterIds(REFGUID ClassGuid)
{
    HDEVINFO hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&ClassGuid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT);
    if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        wprintf(L"Cannot get devices : %d\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    int idx = 0;
    DWORD errorVal = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    while (true)
    {
        SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData = {};
        WCHAR regProp[512];
        devInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(devInfoData);

        if (!SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, idx, &devInfoData))
        {
            errorVal = GetLastError();
            break;
        }

        if (!SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
            hDevInfo,
            &devInfoData,
            SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME,
            NULL,
            (PBYTE)regProp,
            sizeof(regProp),
            NULL))
        {
            errorVal = GetLastError();
            break;
        }

        wprintf(L"Friendly name = %s\n", regProp);

        if (!SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
            hDevInfo,
            &devInfoData,
            SPDRP_HARDWAREID,
            NULL,
            (PBYTE)regProp,
            sizeof(regProp),
            NULL))
        {
            errorVal = GetLastError();
            break;
        }

        // hardwareId is reg_multi_sz
        // Print all of the hardware ids for this device
        PWCHAR pId = regProp;
        do
        {
            wprintf(L"HardwareId = %s\n", pId);
            pId += wcslen(pId) + 1;
        } while (pId[0] != 0);

        // Point to next device
        idx++;
    }

    if (errorVal != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
    {
        printf("Error : %d\n", errorVal);
    }

    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
}

int main()
{
    // {4d36e979-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
    static const GUID PrinterClass =
    { 0x4d36e979, 0xe325, 0x11ce, { 0xbf, 0xc1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe1, 0x03, 0x18 } };
    PrintPrinterIds(PrinterClass);

    // L"{1ed2bbf9-11f0-4084-b21f-ad83a8e6dcdc}"
    static const GUID PrinterQueue =
    { 0x1ed2bbf9, 0x11f0, 0x4084, { 0xb2, 0x1f, 0xad, 0x83, 0xa8, 0xe6, 0xdc, 0xdc } };
    PrintPrinterIds(PrinterQueue);
}
```

Comment: Nice try, it work on local printer, but on remote one I only got : HardwareId = PRINTENUM\LocalPrintQueue and no other info.

Comment: The hardware id + friendly name is the only way to identify the printer. For all RDP redirected printers, the class guid and class information will always be same so you will never be able to identify the redirected printer uniquely based on hardware id/class id/etc. Another parameter that you can add to uniquely identify the printer would be session_user_id+hardware_id+friendly_name. The RDP printer virtual channel providers no other way to uniquely identify the redirected printer. There simply is no PDU defined for it. If this solution does not work, nothing else will work.

Comment: Ok, it's just not possible then I guess. Thanks anyway